# Who is the father of modern PDEs

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Classical PDE theory fails especially when the PDE is nonlinear, i.e. smooth initial data does not imply differentiable solutions. As a result, we often use the notion of weak solution, which has its roots in the theory of distributions in functional analysis. Who connected these two subjects which seem entirely different at least in the first glance. In other words,
who introduced the so called weak formulation/ notion of distributional solutions to PDEs.
Which is the first paper in this direction?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#History), distributions have their origins in the work of Sobolev on PDE. So it seems to me like the connection was always there. [Leray](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-63/issue-none/Sur-le-mouvement-dun-liquide-visqueux-emplissant-lespace/10.1007/BF02547354.full) also uses the weak formulation to study Navier-Stokes years before Schwartz published his treatise on distributions. As for when distributions became **the** tool to use throughout, I don't know.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [History of Science & Math SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).